# Is it more effecient to use std::cout once rather than multiple times to display the same amount of data?

Tags: c++, performance

For example,

Would it be more memory efficient to display these variables like this:

```
std::cout << "First char is " << char1 << " and second char is " << char2;
```

rather than this:

```
std::cout << "First char is " << char1;
std::cout << " and second char is " << char2;
```

Of course, I'm not literally worried about two lines of code.. But I'm trying to learn to write code more efficiently

Thank you

Comment: If you're printing anything to the console the console will be the bottleneck.

Comment: There is no difference what-so-ever. It's all just function calls, and you either pass the argument implicitly (when chaining) or explicitly (when writing a new statement).

Comment: I think the second one is easier to read. That might be more efficient for the people working with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having it be a single statement could theoretically be faster as the compiler can rearrange the order of argument evaluation more freely. However, this is talking about 0.00000000000001% difference and is pointless. Don't care about this - the bottleneck is in the console itself.

Anyway, column alignment is really helpful for readability and so try this:

```
std::cout <<       "First char is " << char1;
std::cout << " and second char is " << char2;
```

Or this:

```
std::cout <<       "First char is " << char1
          << " and second char is " << char2;
```

(I prefer the first because I find it easier to format in my text editor).

Comment: Oh, argument reordering is indeed a good point. Not that I can see how you'd get a performance boost out of it, but hey.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference with programs that small. The toss-up comes with readability. Do u want it quick and easy or more readable?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference for large programs either. You can have a single statement with 10000-chained operators or 10000 statements with no chaining, it'll be the same in the end.